# How to request all chats/groups of the user through Telegram Database Library(TDLib) for Node.js

Tags: node.js, api, node-telegram-bot-api, tdlib

The official example from telegram explains that in order to use `getChats()` command, one needs to set two parameters '`offset_order`' and '`offset_chat_id`'.
I'm using this [node.js wrapper for the TDLib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tglib).
So when I use `getChats()` with the following params:

```
'offset_order': '9223372036854775807',
'offset_chat_id': 0,
'limit': 100
```

just like it is explained in the [official docs](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1get_chats.html):

> For example, to get a list of chats from the beginning, the
>   offset_order should be equal to 2^63 - 1

as a result I get 100 chats from the top of the user's list.

What I can't understand is how do I iterate through that list? How do I use the API pagination?

When I try to enter a legitimate chat_id from the middle of the first 100, I still get the same first 100, so it seems like it makes no difference.

If I change that offset_order to ANY other number, I get an empty list of chats in return...

Completely lost here, as [every](https://github.com/Bannerets/tdl/blob/master/examples/get-chats.js) [single](https://github.com/nodegin/tglib/blob/master/examples/getChats.js) [example](https://github.com/fonbah/tdlnode/blob/master/examples/chats.js) I found says the same thing as the official docs, ie how to get the first 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem, have tried different approaches and re-read documentation for a long time, and here is a decision:

1. do `getChats` as you do with `'9223372036854775807'` `offset_order` parameter
2. do `getChat` request with id of the last chat you have got. It's an offline request, just to tdlib.
3. here you get a chat object with positions property - get a position from here, looks like this:

```
  positions: [
    {
      _: 'chatPosition',
      list: [Object],
      order: '6910658003385450706',
      is_pinned: false
    }
  ],
```

4. next request - `getChats` - use the `positions[0].order` from (3) as `offset_order`
5. goto (2) if there are more chats

It wasn't easy to come to this, so would be glad if it helps anybody who came from google like me :)

Comment: Thank you, it has been such a long time, that I can no longer check the validity of the solution. I will reward the answer, trusting it works.