# How to get other pages of chats from telegram?

Tags: python, telegram

I'm trying to get all chats with python-telegram

```py
tg.login()
res = tg.get_chats(offset_order = off, offset_chat_id = oci, limit=50)
res.wait()
chats=result.update

res=tg.get_chat(chats['chat_ids'][-1])
res.wait()
last_chat = res.update
```

This code returns only first 50 chats from user account.
I'd tried specify off as 2**63-1, and oci as last chat id from array `chats['chat_ids']`, and tried specify off as

```
last_chat['positions'][0]['order'],
```

then anytime `tg.get_chats` returns only top 50 items

How I can get next items?

I've tried miscellaneous values for parameters `offset_order`, `offset_chat_id`, and I have no result.
I need all chats from my telegram account.

[How to request all chats/groups of the user through Telegram Database Library(TDLib) for Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55552416/how-to-request-all-chats-groups-of-the-user-through-telegram-database-librarytd) - this doesn't work...